# Listen to attribute in the same hierarchy level in Firebase DB

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database integrated with an android app and a separated computer that executing a python program with [Firebase-Admin SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python).

In my db i have record of **groups** (the key of each group is an id generated by the db). 
Each group has a list of **group_members** and other non relevant attributes. 
Each group member has it's Firebase Auth id (key) and other attributes.

Now, i wish to set up listener (in the python program) that listens to changes of **group_members** attribute in each group.

Currently i'm just listening to the whole **groups** record and filtering the non relevant events inside the listener:

```
firebase_admin.db.reference('groups').listen(self.my_listener)
```

but there are many attributes that changing very often and i don't need in that specific case.

#### Is it possible to do something like this:

```
firebase_admin.db.reference('groups/*/group_members').listen(self.my_listener)
```

to skip one level of the db hierarchy

Comment: No, this is not supported in the SDKs. Look into something like Cloud Functions for Firebase, which supports wildcards in listen paths: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events